# Need to identify webp images from urls with .jpeg extensions then convert them to true jpg

Tags: php, webp

I have a feed of data that contains car dealer's inventory.  For example:

https://pictures.dealer.com/t/troncallisubarusoa/1849/6aa77e5ac38a3b1f7fe87c15fec40550x.jpg?t=20200708

As you can see, the extension is ".jpg", but if you open the image and try to right click -> save... it shows as a ".webp".  This leads me to believe that it's truly a webp and not a jpg.

This fact is messing up an ffmpeg script that I have since it can't handle webp images.  As a result, I'm trying to create a script that will check inventory urls and try to identify urls that are truly a webp link and then download & convert to a jpeg then store the newly created jpeg in the databse.

I've tried using the exif_imagetype() function as well as viewing the wrapper_data of the url, and both come back with jpg.

Is there a way to determine if the image of a url is a webp?

Comment: It's happening because the server check if the browser supports webp (Using the `accept` header) and if it does then it save the webp version of the file - The extension doesn't matter, it's the mime-type  that define the actual file type. This is used in cases where you don't want to change the code or use fallbacks like the `<picture>` tag

Comment: [Read here](https://www.afasterweb.com/2016/09/30/webp-the-other-image-format/) on how to implement this (Under the _.htaccess (or other server side approaches)_ section)

Comment: Don't store files in databases - https://medium.com/@vaibhav0109/should-i-use-db-to-store-file-410ee22268c7